# What's the meaning of the index of the input port?

Tags: drake

In MIT6.832 HW2 "Cart-Pole: Linearization and LQR Balncing", the carpole is defined as:

```
# instantiate the cart-pole and the scene graph
cartpole, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=0.0)
urdf_path = FindResource('models/undamped_cartpole.urdf')
Parser(cartpole).AddModelFromFile(urdf_path)
cartpole.Finalize()
```

Later on, the carpole's actuation input port is set to be 0:

```
# fix the input port to zero and get its index for the lqr function
cartpole.get_actuation_input_port().FixValue(context, [0])
input_i = cartpole.get_actuation_input_port().get_index() # input_i = 3
```

However, the index of input port is 3, rather than 0, which confuses me mostly here.

---

An extra related question here is that when defining a new system (say, inheriting from  VectorSystem), where could we define the input and output port?

I have been looking at the HW1's cartpole model for a while, and find the port usage is quite confusing. Sometimes it uses `get_xxx_port()` while other cases it uses `get_xxx_port(0)`, with a specific port number inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very reasonable question.

A system in drake can have multiple input ports (or no input ports).  In general, they can be accessed with the [`get_input_port(index)`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1_system.html#a39b7b9f7723ad69fca8766e6590ef681) method.  But if you are building a more complex system with multiple inputs, like `MultibodyPlant`, then you don't want to have to distinguish the different input ports by some index, but by name.  So many systems add extra methods to themselves that provide an additional way to access the same port.  E.g. `MultibodyPlant` offers (the c++ equivalent of)

```
def get_actuation_input_port():
  return get_input_port(3)
```

so that nobody has to remember that the torques go in port 3.  But you can obtain a reference to the port using either method.

Separate from the port index, we need to be able to evaluate an input port for a system given the context.  When the port is "wired up" in a diagram to another system, then a call like `u = cartpole.get_actuation_input_port().Eval(context)` will call the output method of the other system.  But it's also useful to be able to set the input to just be a constant value, so we offer that interface, too.  That's what is happening in your snippet above:

```
cartpole.get_actuation_input_port().FixValue(context, [0])
```

This line is setting the value of the input port in the context to be a vector -- which happens here to be a vector of size 1, with that sole element being zero.  For a robot that has four actuators, it might have been

```
my_robot.get_actuation_input_port().FixValue(context, [0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: For your other question, about adding input ports, you might look at the tutorial on the drake homepage:  https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/RobotLocomotion/drake/nightly-release?filepath=tutorials/dynamical_systems.ipynb
which shows how to declare input and output ports.

Comment: Aha, I see. I misunderstood the meaning of "fix the input port to zero". I thought it means fixing the `input port`'s index = 0. So the purpose of fixing the input of carpole is to set `u=0` and linearize the system \dot_{x} = f(x=x_start, u=0)?